# levelplot in lattice R: How to get right number of decimals displayed in cells

Tags: r, lattice, levelplot

Working with levelplot in lattice, I have figured out how to display the corresponding value of each cell. For a matrix m:

```
myPanel <- function(x,y,z, ...){
 panel.levelplot(x,y,z,...) 
 panel.text(x,y, round(m,2),col=bw[col.m])
}
levelplot(m, col.regions=col.range, colorkey=NULL, xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL,
      scales = list(x = list(draw = FALSE),  y = list(draw = FALSE)),
      panel= myPanel)
```

The rounded matrix values are

```
round(m,2)
     13    14    15    16    17    18
GDcsp -0.44 -0.34 -0.39 -0.35 -0.53 -0.60
GDsor  0.14  0.07  0.03  0.01  0.06  0.09
GDdup  0.43  0.36  0.34  0.36  0.46  0.52
GDhsw  0.22  0.05  0.11  0.00  0.20  0.26
Gdwpa  0.17  0.25  0.32  0.37  0.46  0.47
```

The problem is that -0.60 and 0.00 are displayed in the corresponding cell as 0.6 and 0, respectively, while I would like to have all numbers with two decimals. Any idea to solve this would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myPanel <- function(x,y,z, ...){
  panel.levelplot(x,y,z,...) 
  panel.text(x,y, sprintf("%.2f", m))
}
levelplot(m, colorkey=NULL, xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL,
          scales = list(x = list(draw = FALSE),  y = list(draw = FALSE)),
          panel= myPanel)
```

You can use `sprintf` to force the output to be 2 decimal places.